# Is it possible to add a custom Header with AWS Lambda (HTTP API)

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, aws-http-api

I'm using a custom authentication with `AWS Lambda` on my `API Gateway HTTP API`. Currently, if auth pass, it will return like this:

```
return {
    'isAuthorized': True,
    'context': {
        'userId': user_id
    }
}
```

I'm aware that with `REST API` its possible to use mappers and set a custom headers. But is it viable with `HTTP API`? I want to pass to my application a header `X-AUTH-USER-ID` with the value of `context.userId`

Comment: Yes, you can return custom headers for HTTP api as shown [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/http-api-develop-integrations-lambda.html#http-api-develop-integrations-lambda.response). Do you require other type of headers?

Comment: Hello @Marcin, I just tried to remove `context`, I have replaced it by `"headers": {  "X-AUTH-USER-ID": user_id }` but the header was missing on my application still

Comment: Can you provide more info, how do you call it, reproducible lambda function code, is it http integration v1 or v2? What is `isAuthorized`? There is no such field in the aws docs for response format.

Comment: This is an authorizer, you can find its docs [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/http-api-lambda-authorizer.html). I'm using v2. This is my authorizer, my integration is just a load balancer.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the link. Haven't noticed before.